# jOOQ - Got string literal too long exception for Long Query generated as a step

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, jooq

I am using Jooq to construct a merge statement using merge step, like this:

```java
MergeNotMatchedSetMoreStep<InventoryRecord> mergeInsert =
    mergeUpdate
        .whenNotMatchedThenInsert()
        .set(EMPLOYEE.COLLECTEDAT, now)
        .set(EMPLOYEE.VALID, true);

for (Field<?> setField : EMPLOYEE.fields()) {
  if (setField == EMPLOYEE.COLLECTEDAT) continue;
  if (setField == EMPLOYEE.VALID) continue;
  Field<?> setValue = EMPLOYEE_VIEW.field(setField.getUnqualifiedName());
  mergeInsert = mergeInsert.set((Field<Object>) setField, setValue);
}
```

As you can see above, I am making a dynamic query and finally executing the same in the database.
Database used is Oracle 11g (also tested it on upgraded compatible versions but no luck)

I have tagged jOOQ because I am not sure whether my way of constructing the query is causing the issue, or is it the oracle which is throwing an error.

```
mergeInsert.execute(); // a very long generated at this line and got an exception here
```

Error:

```
"org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: Error while running ConnectionCallable at
org.jooq_3.12.0.ORACLE11G.debug(Unknown Source) at 
org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.connectionResult(DefaultDSLContext.java:658) at 
org.jooq.impl.ExplainQuery.explain(ExplainQuery.java:66) at 
org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.explain(DefaultDSLContext.java:481) at 
net.company.retirements.web.perf.QueryPerformanceLogger$QueryMetrics.addTimedRun(QueryPerformanceLogger.java:207) at
net.company.retirements.web.perf.QueryPerformanceLogger$1.executeEnd(QueryPerformanceLogger.java:61) at 
org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.executeEnd(ExecuteListeners.java:191) at 
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:295) at
org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:369) at 
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:501) at
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:470) at 
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(AbstractResultQuery.java:484) at
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchOne(AbstractResultQuery.java:653) at
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchOne(AbstractResultQuery.java:605) at
org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchOne(AbstractResultQuery.java:611) at
org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchOne(SelectImpl.java:2847) at 
net.company.dataset.query.TypedQuery.count(TypedQuery.java:297) at 
net.company.dataset.http.DataSetResponse.fromRequest(DataSetResponse.java:70) at 
net.company.retirements.web.controllers.RequestsController.availableEquipments(RequestsController.java:226)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.ja
va:189)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerM
ethod.java:138)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHan
dle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandler
Method(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInterna
l(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMe
thodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\n\ta
t org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)\n\tat 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\n\tat 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:28
6)\n\tat 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:26
0)\n\tat 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)\n\tat 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)\n\tat 
weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)\n\tat 
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat 
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFi
lter.java:169)\n\tat 
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:12
6)\n\tat org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)\n\tat 
org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)\n\t
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat 
net.company.retirements.web.filters.NotificationFilter.doFilter(NotificationFilter.java:36)\n\ta
t 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:3
57)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\
tat weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat 
net.company.retirements.web.filters.IdleSessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(IdleSessionTimeoutFilter.j
ava:43)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:3
57)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\
tat weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat 
net.company.retirements.web.filters.GlobalBeansInRequestFilter.doFilter(GlobalBeansInRequestFilt
er.java:65)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:3
57)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\
tat weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.j
ava:320)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurit
yInterceptor.java:127)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)\n\tat net.company.security.filters.ToggleableFilter.doFilter(ToggleableFilter.java:44)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat net.company.retirements.web.filters.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:25)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)\n\tat weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)\n\tat weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)\n\tat weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)\n\tat weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)\n\tat weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)\n\tat weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)\n\tat weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)\n\tat weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)\n\tat weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)\n\tat weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:\nPLS-00172: string literal too long\n\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:220)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:48)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:938)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4901)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5631)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)\n\tat weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:119)\n\tat org.jooq.impl.ExplainQuery$1.run(ExplainQuery.java:83)\n\tat org.jooq.impl.ExplainQuery$1.run(ExplainQuery.java:66)\n\tat org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.connectionResult(DefaultDSLContext.java:655)\n\t... 130 more
```

SQL query being generated:

```
merge into "RET_EMPLOYEE" using ((select "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."EMPLOYEEID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."TYPE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."IDENTIFIER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATIONID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEMARKET", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEREGION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATOR", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONGROUP", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONREGION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONMARKET", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONTYPEID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PART", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PARTID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."DESCRIPTION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PARTSERIALIZED", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."CONTAINERCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."STATUS", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."STATUSID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNITID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNIT", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."MFGPARTNUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."MANUFACTURER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOTNUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."USAGECODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."FAID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."DISPOSITIONCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VALUE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SERIALNUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."QUANTITY", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."QTYAVAILABLE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."FRACTION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORNAME", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."OWNERCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PROJECTCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POLINENUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."COST", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."COST2", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POCOST", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."TAXVALUE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."OPSVALUE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ACTIVE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETWARRANTYID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDORID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDOR", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYSTARTDATE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYENDDATE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."UNDERWARRANTY", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."EXPIRESINMONTHS" from "RET_V_EMPLOYEE" where 1 = 1)) "RET_V_EMPLOYEE" on ("RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."EMPLOYEEID" = "RET_EMPLOYEE"."EMPLOYEEID") when matched then update set "RET_EMPLOYEE"."COLLECTEDAT" = ?, "RET_EMPLOYEE"."VALID" = ?, "RET_EMPLOYEE"."TYPE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."TYPE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."IDENTIFIER" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."IDENTIFIER", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATIONID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATIONID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATION" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATION", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEMARKET" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEMARKET", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEREGION" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEREGION", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATOR" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATOR", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATION" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATION", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONGROUP" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONGROUP", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONREGION" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONREGION", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONMARKET" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONMARKET", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONTYPEID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONTYPEID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."PART" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PART", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."PARTID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PARTID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."DESCRIPTION" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."DESCRIPTION", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."PARTSERIALIZED" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PARTSERIALIZED", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."CONTAINERCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."CONTAINERCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."STATUS" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."STATUS", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."STATUSID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."STATUSID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNITID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNITID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNIT" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNIT", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."MFGPARTNUMBER" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."MFGPARTNUMBER", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."MANUFACTURER" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."MANUFACTURER", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."LOTNUMBER" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOTNUMBER", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."USAGECODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."USAGECODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."FAID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."FAID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."DISPOSITIONCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."DISPOSITIONCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."VALUE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VALUE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."SERIALNUMBER" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SERIALNUMBER", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."QUANTITY" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."QUANTITY", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."QTYAVAILABLE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."QTYAVAILABLE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORNAME" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORNAME", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."OWNERCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."OWNERCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."PROJECTCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PROJECTCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."POCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."POLINENUMBER" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POLINENUMBER", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."COST" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."COST", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."COST2" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."COST2", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."POCOST" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POCOST", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."TAXVALUE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."TAXVALUE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."OPSVALUE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."OPSVALUE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."ACTIVE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ACTIVE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETWARRANTYID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETWARRANTYID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDORID" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDORID", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYCODE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYCODE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDOR" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDOR", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYSTARTDATE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYSTARTDATE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYENDDATE" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYENDDATE", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."UNDERWARRANTY" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."UNDERWARRANTY", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."EXPIRESINMONTHS" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."EXPIRESINMONTHS", "RET_EMPLOYEE"."FRACTION" = "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."FRACTION" when not matched then insert ("COLLECTEDAT", "VALID", "EMPLOYEEID", "TYPE", "IDENTIFIER", "SOURCELOCATIONID", "SOURCELOCATION", "SOURCEMARKET", "SOURCEREGION", "LOCATOR", "LOCATION", "LOCATIONID", "LOCATIONGROUP", "LOCATIONREGION", "LOCATIONMARKET", "LOCATIONTYPEID", "PART", "PARTID", "DESCRIPTION", "PARTSERIALIZED", "CONTAINERCODE", "STATUS", "STATUSID", "BUSINESSUNITID", "BUSINESSUNIT", "MFGPARTNUMBER", "MANUFACTURER", "LOTNUMBER", "USAGECODE", "FAID", "ASSETCODE", "DISPOSITIONCODE", "VALUE", "SERIALNUMBER", "QUANTITY", "QTYAVAILABLE", "VENDORID", "VENDORCODE", "VENDORNAME", "OWNERCODE", "PROJECTCODE", "POCODE", "POLINENUMBER", "COST", "COST2", "POCOST", "TAXVALUE", "OPSVALUE", "ACTIVE", "ASSETWARRANTYID", "WARRANTYVENDORID", "WARRANTYCODE", "WARRANTYVENDOR", "WARRANTYSTARTDATE", "WARRANTYENDDATE", "UNDERWARRANTY", "EXPIRESINMONTHS", "FRACTION") values (?, ?, "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."EMPLOYEEID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."TYPE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."IDENTIFIER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATIONID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCELOCATION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEMARKET", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SOURCEREGION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATOR", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONGROUP", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONREGION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONMARKET", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOCATIONTYPEID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PART", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PARTID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."DESCRIPTION", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PARTSERIALIZED", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."CONTAINERCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."STATUS", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."STATUSID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNITID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."BUSINESSUNIT", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."MFGPARTNUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."MANUFACTURER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."LOTNUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."USAGECODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."FAID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."DISPOSITIONCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VALUE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."SERIALNUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."QUANTITY", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."QTYAVAILABLE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."VENDORNAME", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."OWNERCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."PROJECTCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POLINENUMBER", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."COST", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."COST2", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."POCOST", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."TAXVALUE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."OPSVALUE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ACTIVE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."ASSETWARRANTYID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDORID", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYCODE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYVENDOR", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYSTARTDATE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."WARRANTYENDDATE", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."UNDERWARRANTY", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."EXPIRESINMONTHS", "RET_V_EMPLOYEE"."FRACTION")
```

Target Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RET_EMPLOYEE
(
    EMPLOYEEID       VARCHAR2(41)
        CONSTRAINT RET_EMPLOYEEPK PRIMARY KEY,
    TYPE              VARCHAR2(5),
    IDENTIFIER        NUMBER,
    COLLECTEDAT       TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
    VALID             CHAR,
    SOURCELOCATIONID  NUMBER,
    SOURCELOCATION    VARCHAR2(100),
    SOURCEMARKET      VARCHAR2(50),
    SOURCEREGION      VARCHAR2(150),
    LOCATOR           VARCHAR2(50),
    LOCATION          VARCHAR2(100),
    LOCATIONID        NUMBER,
    LOCATIONGROUP     VARCHAR2(50),
    LOCATIONREGION    VARCHAR2(150),
    LOCATIONMARKET    VARCHAR2(50),
    LOCATIONTYPEID    NUMBER,
    PART              VARCHAR2(50),
    PARTID            NUMBER,
    DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR2(255),
    PARTSERIALIZED    CHAR,
    CONTAINERCODE     VARCHAR2(50),
    STATUS            VARCHAR2(50),
    STATUSID          NUMBER,
    BUSINESSUNITID    NUMBER,
    BUSINESSUNIT      VARCHAR2(101),
    MFGPARTNUMBER     VARCHAR2(50),
    MANUFACTURER      VARCHAR2(50),
    LOTNUMBER         VARCHAR2(50),
    USAGECODE         VARCHAR2(50),
    FAID              VARCHAR2(50),
    ASSETCODE         VARCHAR2(50),
    DISPOSITIONCODE   VARCHAR2(50),
    VALUE             NUMBER,
    SERIALNUMBER      VARCHAR2(50),
    QUANTITY          NUMBER,
    QTYAVAILABLE      NUMBER,
    VENDORID          NUMBER,
    VENDORCODE        VARCHAR2(50),
    VENDORNAME        VARCHAR2(255),
    OWNERCODE         VARCHAR2(50),
    PROJECTCODE       VARCHAR2(50),
    POCODE            VARCHAR2(50),
    POLINENUMBER      VARCHAR2(50),
    COST              NUMBER,
    COST2             NUMBER,
    POCOST            NUMBER,
    TAXVALUE          NUMBER,
    OPSVALUE          NUMBER,
    ACTIVE            CHAR,
    ASSETWARRANTYID   NUMBER,
    WARRANTYVENDORID  NUMBER,
    WARRANTYCODE      VARCHAR2(50),
    WARRANTYVENDOR    VARCHAR2(255),
    WARRANTYSTARTDATE DATE,
    WARRANTYENDDATE   DATE,
    UNDERWARRANTY     VARCHAR2(1),
    EXPIRESINMONTHS   NUMBER,
    FRACTION CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N'
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX RET_EMPLOYEEI1 ON RET_EMPLOYEE (TYPE, IDENTIFIER);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX RET_EMPLOYEEI2 ON RET_EMPLOYEE (VALID, COLLECTEDAT);
```

Comment: What's the SQL query that is being generated by jOOQ? ([See here on how to obtain it](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-execute-logging/)). Also, what are your `MERGE` statement's source and target table `CREATE TABLE` definitions?

Comment: @LukasEder - Thanks for the prompt reply. I have added the generated query in the above question body.

Comment: Thanks. What about the source and target table's `CREATE TABLE` definitions? I.e. the `CREATE TABLE RET_EMPLOYEE` and `CREATE TABLE RET_V_EMPLOYEE` definition. Specifically, I'm interested in all the relevant data types of each column

Comment: @LukasEder -  Sure, I've uploaded the target table's body (RET_EMPLOYEE) here. Since the body's limit is exceeding, here is the definition of both definitions on google doc:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H8p4Fnx6c0euAVK9T7oAOgnpPKG_L26MnM4EQQD3d4g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, that's a view. Huh, I can't help you there easily, without having the entire schema involved at my disposition. The problem is (probably) that one of your source data points is too wide for your target table. The error message isn't very helpful to show what column is causing this. But you will probably have to widen your `RET_EMPLOYEE` column(s).

Comment: @LukasEder - I got an interesting observation. I was logging performance of each query using jooq's 'explain' utility. Here's the sample:
db.explain(DSL.query(worstSql.replaceAll("'", "''")))
I think, the replaceAll might be causing problem. Or the DSL.query might be causing it. The query is TOOO LOOOONG.